# How to use declarative macros to generate a self containing enum?

Tags: recursion, rust

I want to create a declarative macro that simplifies a recursive creation of an enum structure (by hiding all the `Box::new`). However commas seem to cause a problem when having a deep formula that has commas in its substructures.

Here is an explanation in code:

Assume this definition for an Enum representing a subset of propositional logic

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum PFormula {
    True,
    False,
    Atom(i32),
    Not(Box<PFormula>),
    And(Box<PFormula>, Box<PFormula>)
}

macro_rules! pformula {
    ($func:tt($($($sub:tt)+),+)) => { PFormula::$func($(Box::new($sub)+),+) };
    (True) => { PFormula::True };
    (False) => { PFormula::False };
    ($e:expr) => { PFormula::Atom($e) };
}

fn main() {
    
    let x = pformula!(And(Not(2), 3));
    let y = pformula!(And(And(1, 4), And(5, And(2, 6))));
    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

The `pformula` should take a simplified version of the syntax defined as the `enum` and create a `PFormula` representation by hiding all the `Box<PFormula>`'s required for the recursive structure. What is happening is that there seems to be an ambiguity when handling the commas.

So the `x` in the above code should expand to:

```rust
PFormula::And(Box::new(PFormula::Not(Box::new(PFormula::Atom(2)))), Box::new(PFormula::Atom(3)))
```

However this is the error returned

```rust
error: local ambiguity when calling macro `pformula`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('sub') or 1 other option.
  --> src/main.rs:18:33
   |
18 |     let x = pformula!(And(Not(2), 3));
   |                                 ^

error: local ambiguity when calling macro `pformula`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('sub') or 1 other option.
  --> src/main.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let y = pformula!(And(And(1, 4), And(5, And(2, 6))));
   |                                    ^

error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

Please note that this is a simplification of the syntax I am actually working on. The syntax I am using has around 8 variants of arity 1 and around 5 of arity 2, so having a match arm for each variant seemed like an overkill. Additionally I tried it and it still was not working because of the commas.

So the question, is there a way to do this in declarative macros or is this better solved using function-like proc macros?

Comment: The ambiguity is because `,` is a `tt`, so there is ambiguity between matching more of one argument or a comma separating multiple arguments. I don't have a solution to suggest, though.

Comment: You can use tt munching.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you for the suggestion! I tried looking into the TT munching. It works like a charm for variants with an arity less than 2. However, variants with an arity of 2 did not work, such as the And(x,y) variant. In it, I have to find where to wrap two formulas in a Box compared to a unary variant like Not.